# New Bicycles user with commercial connection?

Tags: discussion, spam, new-users

Specifically referring to this user, who has made ~7 postings in the last 24 hours.

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/23036/velosurance

I feel their input could be relevant and useful, but they need to be guided in some form.

My question is - what can we do to help them be a more useful contributor?

Comment: Seems like being a useful contributor is independent of commercial connections. I'd direct them to read the SE docs but as far as being commercial, that doesn't automatically make their contributions of lesser quality. If they are flagrantly linking to products or promoting they should be down voted.